# How to receive data from BLE device on android app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, device, android-bluetooth

I am new to android studio and creating apps and this is part of a project I am doing.

I am able to connect to the Bluetooth device and be able to get it into onServicesDiscovered function with the status GATT_SUCCESS.

I am not sure where to go from here since I am not receiving data from the device. Do I need a broadcast update or broadcast receiver or is the code below fine but needs to be fixed?

If anyone can help that would be great!

```js
@Override
        //New services discovered
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", "Status: " + status);
            if(status == GATT_SUCCESS) {
                List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
                
                for(BluetoothGattService service : services){
                    if(!service.getUuid().equals("49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9-9FAFD205E455"))
                        continue;
                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = service.getCharacteristics();

                    // Loops through available Characteristics
                    for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics){
                        if(!gattCharacteristic.getUuid().equals("49535343-1E4D-4BD9-BA61-23C647249616"))
                            continue;

                        final int charaProp = gattCharacteristic.getProperties();

                        if((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0){
                            setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                            Log.w(TAG, "Working");
                        }else{
                            Log.w(TAG, "Characteristic does not support notify");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered receive: " + status);
            }
                //List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
                //Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());
                //gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(0));
            
        }

        @Override
        //Result of a characteristic read operation
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());
            if(status != GATT_SUCCESS){
                Log.e(TAG, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "ERROR: Read failed for characteristic: %s, status %d", characteristic.getUuid(), status));
                completedCommand();
                return;
            }
            //gatt.disconnect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            if (status == GATT_SUCCESS) {
                if (descriptor.getCharacteristic().getUuid().equals(UUID_TARGET_CHARACTERISTIC)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed");
                }

                byte[] data = {1, 1};
                BluetoothGattService Service = mGatt.getService(UUID_TARGET_SERVICE);

                BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service.getCharacteristic(UUID_TARGET_CHARACTERISTIC);

                charac.setValue(data);
                mGatt.readCharacteristic(charac);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error subscribing");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
            Log.i("BLE", "receive value ----------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                Log.w("BLE", "character_value = " + value[i]);
            }
            //processData(characteristic.getValue());
        }
    };

    public boolean readCharacteristic(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if(mGatt == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: Gatt is 'null', ignoring read request");
            return false;
        }

        // Check if characteristic is valid
        if(characteristic == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: Characteristic is 'null', ignoring read request");
            return false;
        }

        // Check if this characteristic actually has READ property
        if((characteristic.getProperties() & PROPERTY_READ) == 0 ) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: Characteristic cannot be read");
            return false;
        }

        // Enqueue the read command now that all checks have been passed
        boolean result = commandQueue.add(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(!mGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                    Log.e(TAG, String.format("ERROR: readCharacteristic failed for characteristic: %s", characteristic.getUuid()));
                    completedCommand();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("reading characteristic <%s>", characteristic.getUuid()));
                    nrTries++;
                }
            }
        });

        if(result) {
            nextCommand();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: Could not enqueue read characteristic command");
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void nextCommand() {
        // If there is still a command being executed then bail out
        if(commandQueueBusy) {
            return;
        }

        // Check if we still have a valid gatt object
        if (mGatt == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("ERROR: GATT is 'null' for peripheral '%s', clearing command queue", device.getAddress()));
            commandQueue.clear();
            commandQueueBusy = false;
            return;
        }

        // Execute the next command in the queue
        if (commandQueue.size() > 0) {
            final Runnable bluetoothCommand = commandQueue.peek();
            commandQueueBusy = true;
            nrTries = 0;

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        bluetoothCommand.run();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, String.format("ERROR: Command exception for device '%s'", device.getName()), ex);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void retryCommand() {
        commandQueueBusy = false;
        Runnable currentCommand = commandQueue.peek();
        if(currentCommand != null) {
            if (nrTries >= MAX_TRIES) {
                // Max retries reached, give up on this one and proceed
                Log.v(TAG, "Max number of tries reached");
                commandQueue.poll();
            } else {
                //isRetrying = true;
            }
        }
        nextCommand();
    }

    private void completedCommand() {
        commandQueueBusy = false;
        //isRetrying = false;
        commandQueue.poll();
        nextCommand();
    }

    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) {
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null || mGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(BTMODULEUUID);
        descriptor.setValue(enabled?BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE :BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to turn on notifications to receive data from your BLE device and you used `setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);` for that purpose. But this is not enough. It will only tell the Bluetooth Stack that this characteristic will send notifications, but you also want to subscribe to the notifications on your device.

For that you need the so called CCC descriptor and write [ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattDescriptor#ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE) to it:

```
private final String CCC_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
final BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(CCC_DESCRIPTOR_UUID));
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Doing both will enable notifications for this device. Have a look at this awesome [Guide](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/) from PunchTrough for more informations on using BLE.

Comment: Thanks @kotzjan that makes sense, I have modified those lines of code inside the setCharacteristicNotification function. But what is the CCC_DESCRIPTOR_UUID assigned to?

Comment: For the BLE device I am connecting to the data sheet does not give me a UUID for the client characteristic descriptor

Comment: I just choose a CCC for TX option (read). I think you pick either to read or write for the CCC unless you have a function that deals with both?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i missed that variable. I'll edit the answer!

Comment: The uuid of the CCCD is always the same, it works only in the context of a characteristic. See: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/23515/why-all-cccds-have-the-same-uuid

Comment: I was able to get a tag saying that setCharacteristicNotification() is enabled to true but I think after that I am still not able to read data. Is the problem somewhere in the onDescriptorRead or onCharacteristicChanged?

Comment: Is the following line calling the writeDescriptor function: mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor); or is it going to onDescriptorRead()?

Comment: I actually was able to receive the data, perhaps it was in an idle state because on the MicroChip Explorer board the program on MPLab was not compiled and running. Either way I was able to read data.

Comment: Glad you solved it on your own! writeDescriptor writes the descriptor, but you receive an answer from your device on onDescriptorRead. You can ignore these by filtering for the CCCD uuid.